# How to bind to a property of the parent of the item which is the DataContext?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a group of controls in a StackPanel container, in a user control, bound to different properties to an item which is the DataContext of the container, set as {Binding MyItem}

How would I bind one of those controls to the logical parent of this MyItem, if MyItem object has a property pointing to its parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MyItem has a property pointing to its parent, then you can directly use that property to reference the Parent. Nothing special required for it, like:

```
{Binding Parent.PropertyName}
```

(unless I misunderstood the question)

Comment: Thank you; although this works, having a public property Parent now creates an infinite loop when I try saving the binary tree of MyItem objects, because parent saves child which saves parent, etc. I am now seeking ways to customize this serialization process.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that {Binding Path=Parent.IsEnabled} was enough, provided that the item which is the DataContext has a public property Parent. Probably earlier errors were due to other things.